# error regexp django urls

Tags: regex, django

my **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from home.views import homePageView, activateUser

urlpatterns = [
    path('',homePageView.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/$', activateUser.activate, name='activate')
]
```

the url on the browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/activate/9Eri2DOMYpwI5p8/
```

**error:**

```
  Using the URLconf defined in cryptoassistant.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/ [name='home'] activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/$ [name='activate'] activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/$ [name='activate'] The current path, activate/9Eri2DOMYpwI5p8/, didn't match any of these.
```

django generate this error..some one suggest !!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regexps with the `path` function which came in as upgrade over `url` in Django 2.

replace

```
path('activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/$', activateUser.activate, name='activate')
```

to

```
path('activate/<slug:slug>)/$', activateUser.activate, name='activate')
```

If you want to name something else to named parameter change second slug to that name.

**example**

```
path('activate/<slug:other_name>/$', activateUser.activate, name='activate')
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to upvote and accept answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You (or me ;) )  can use this:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
re_path('activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', activateUser.activate, name='activate')
```